# Docker rails elastic search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to implement elastic search in my rails web app. I am using docker. I used [this link](http://nyonura.com/blog/2016/Setting-Up-Elasticsearch-In-Rails-Using-Docker/) for reference. My docker-compose.yml file is:

```
 mysql:
  image: mysql:5.6.34
  ports:
    - "3002:3002"
  volumes_from:
    - dbdata
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=dev

dbdata:
  image: tianon/true
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/mysql

web:
  build: .
  environment:
    RAILS_ENV: development
  ports:
    - '3000:3000'
  volumes_from:
    - appdata
  links:
    - "mysql"
    - elasticsearch

appdata:
  image: tianon/true
  volumes:
    - ".:/workspace"

elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
  ulimits:
    memlock:
      soft: -1
      hard: -1
    nofile:
      soft: 65536
      hard: 65536
  mem_limit: 1g
  cap_add:
    - IPC_LOCK
  volumes:
    - /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

When I am trying to run `Student.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force:true` as indicated in the above given link. I am getting following error:[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to set *ENV* for `ELASTICSEARCH_URL` to correct value

```
ELASTICSEARCH_URL="http://<ip-of-your-docker-container>:9200"
```

As you have linked network, you can provide as bellow

```
ELASTICSEARCH_URL="http://elasticsearch:9200"
```

> Links allow you to define extra aliases by which a service is reachable from another service. Any service can reach any other service at that service’s name

If no *ENV* is set, your rails app will use `http://localhost:9200`

Comment: the problem remains the same. I have added 'ELASTICSEARCH_URL="http://67850028bc9c45b6d43067743d3b7dd70dbd66138aba2f5693c6bd88a45fa63c:9500"'

Comment: How did you pass this ENV? and what is this inside this `ENV ="......"`

Comment: I have not included ENV variable. I have just added the ELASTICSEARCH_URL="http://<ip-of-my-docker-container>:9200" in docker-compose.yml file under the environment of web section. Please help  me out from the above problem.

Comment: How did you get your contaier IP address?